# How to make gmail search box similar ui in gwt

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gxt

We are making an application using GWT that require a search box widget like gmail has.
I dont know how and where to start to make such widget. 
Basically what widget/component should i use to make a text box with a dropdown icon,where if i click the dropdown icon it opens a panel with advanced search using gwt.Please help

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, take a look at the GWT `SuggestionBox` and maybe [this](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/creating_a_facebook_style_autocomplete). If you mean implementing a comprehensive search like they have, look about Lucene

Comment: nope,not like that.in gmail we have a search box where you type in and u get the result.but in that serach box at the corner there is a dropdown icon where if u click a advanced search panel opens,where you have text boxes buttons etc.so i want to make a widget with similar text box and advanced search panel.
Neways thanx for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with UiBinder tool, you can design fastly what you wish :

`

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:VerticalPanel>
        <g:HorizontalPanel>
            <g:TextBox/>
            <g:PushButton text="V" ui:field="pushButton"/>
            <g:PushButton text="Search"/>
        </g:HorizontalPanel>
        <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="optionsPanel">
            <g:HorizontalPanel>
                <g:Label text="Foo"/>
                <g:TextBox/>
            </g:HorizontalPanel>
            <g:HorizontalPanel>
                <g:Label text="Bar"/>
                <g:TextBox/>
            </g:HorizontalPanel>
        </g:VerticalPanel>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

`

and 
`
package yde.dev.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.PushButton;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;

public class SearchLikeGmail extends Composite {

```
private static SearchLikeGmailUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(SearchLikeGmailUiBinder.class);
@UiField VerticalPanel optionsPanel;
@UiField PushButton moreOptionsBttn;

interface SearchLikeGmailUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, SearchLikeGmail> {
}

public SearchLikeGmail() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    optionsPanel.setVisible( false );
}

@UiHandler("moreOptionsBttn")
void onMoreOptionsBttnClick(ClickEvent event) {
    optionsPanel.setVisible( true );
}
```

}
`

Comment: Thnx Overnuts,i didnt know about the use of uibinders.actually i am new to gwt .i will give it a try after the weekend.if it works i 'll definitely accept ur answer.i'll let u know by Tuesday if it worked.thanx again.

Comment: Into eclipse, get the "java" perspective (not EE), right click your project, new > uibinder